# Converting sync code (with BinaryReader) to using async/await for NetworkStream

Tags: c#

I'm trying to figure out how to wait for data on a `NetworkStream` using the task based async / wait approach recommended by Microsoft.

so far im just looping untill data becomes available, whch is probaby bad:

```
using (NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream())
{
    while (true)
    {
        if (stream.CanRead && stream.DataAvailable)
        {
            using(BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                byte data = reader.ReadByte();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it suppose to work pretty much the same way as the usual methods, simply add the async/await keywords.

Comment: No code, dont even know where to start

Comment: At least start with something even if it isn't using `async`/`await`: 
`            // should use TaskCancellationToken to properly shut this thread down
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
               while (_tcpClient.Connected) {
                  if (_tcpClient.GetStream().DataAvailable) {
                     var msgBuffer = GetNetworkStream();
                     OnMessageBytesReceived(msgBuffer);
                  }

                  Thread.Sleep(1);  // 1ms sleep
               }
            });
`

Comment: @IAbstract, thas is a nice answer, gues i was hoping for built in support somehow

Comment: Voting to reopen as now question have code to start from. (Updated title to highlight request of converting to async).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I think it's fairly trivial to implement a read loop, might be worth changing your now deleted answer.

Comment: @Charlieface Thanks. I deleted the answer as there is still no way to read single byte async using specific function as asked in this question. Loop to get more bytes is unrelated to the question asked here (the way I read the question).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov You can just do a simple loop `var buffer = new byte[size]; int totalRead = 0; int bytesRead = 0; while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, totalRead, size - totalRead) > 0) totalRead += bytesRead;` with possibly an extra check if the loop ended early. An alternative C-style `for` loop would be `for (var bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, totalRead, size - totalRead); bytesRead > 0; totalRead += bytesRead) {}`